# Find out how long until Settimer timer triggers in Autohotkey

Tags: timer, autohotkey

In AKH I can set a timer that is executed once in a minute with the command

```
Settimer, MyLabel, -60000
return

MyLabel:
msgbox, do something
return
```

Once the timer is running, **can I check within autohotkey how many seconds are left on the timer without cheating?** An example for cheating is storing the time when I started the timer in a variable and comparing agaist that value...

Comment: I don't think that's possible per se. What's the problem with "*cheating*"? I don't see a reason why it would be problematic to store the last timer run separately.

Comment: The problem with cheating is that it would require complicated code if I use `Settimer, off` and `Settimer, on` a lot - as well as a handfull of different timers - so basically I had to write my own timer management. Much easier to ask a certain timer its status.

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to do that. But is it really that complicated? The way I see it, you'd only have to store the time of the current run within `MyLabel` (e.g. `MyLabel: lastRun := A_TickCount ...`). And maybe null the variable when you disable the timer. You could easily build functions for that [like `EnableTimer(timerName, period)` and `DisableTimer(timerName)`].

Comment: There already seem to exist solutions for that: [(1)](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/42868-detect-timer-time-remaining-gettimer/) and [(2)](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/93687-function-timer/)